# verify validation code in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to verify email by sending a code, the first step is to generate the code wheneever the user enters his email, send him the code in the mail then verify this code and return a response.
that's how i'm approaching the problem:
I created a model named Email_for_Verification ith two fields (email , code) the code is generated randomly, i create an instance of this model when the user enters his email, i send the generated code on email, in the second step, the user enters the received code, and i'm proceeding to the validation with a View named : Verify_code.
but i'm encountring an error

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'code'
```

i have the follwing auestions is it the true approach ?
why am i encountring this error ?

Here is my code:

Models.py

```
def generate_activation_code():
    return int(''.join([str(random.randint(0,10)) for _ in range(6)]))

class Email_for_Verification(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name='email', unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=generate_activation_code)
```

Views.py

```
class Verify_code(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        code = data.get('code')
        email = data.get('email')
        email_for_verification = models.Email_for_Verification.objects.filter(email=email)
        if code == email_for_verification.code:
            return Response({"valid" : "Valid code", "email": email}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Response sent in browsable api:

```
{
"email":"dummy@mail.com",
"code":487954
}
```

Please note that i had already generated a code for this email from the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` retuns a list of objects. You need to use `get()`

```
models.Email_for_Verification.objects.get(email=email)
```

Comment: email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name='email', unique=True), the email field is unique.

Comment: No, this was a response to another comment but that person deleted it.

Comment: but if the user entered a wrong code, and after that he needed to register amother time, how can i handle that ? i think that i hqve to regenrate new code because the email he entered is already in my data base or should iput it not unique ?